# custom sql parameter using IN clause in gridview - C#

Tags: c#, sql

When I placed the the following SQL query,

```
SELECT
   [ItemID], [Name], [RelDate], [Price], [Status] 
FROM 
   [item_k] 
WHERE 
   [ItemID] IN (" + itemIDs + ")
```

in gridview custom sql statements, it gets transformed to,

```
SELECT 
   ItemID, Name, RelDate, Price, Status   
FROM 
   item_k 
WHERE 
   (ItemID IN ([ + itemIDs + ]))
```

and when I execute the query the following error is shown

```
SQL Execution Error
Invalid column name '+ itemIDs+'
```

what seems to be the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting + itemIDs+ in single quotes?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your string concat method is that it would possibly leave you vulnerable to SQL injection. I wouldn't try to fix this approach, but go for a a parameterized query that doesn't require string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [ItemID], [Name], [RelDate], [Price], [Status] FROM [item_k] WHERE [ItemID] IN (' + itemIDs + ')
```

changed " to ' and it worked!